# Redux Actions And Shared Validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I have an array of *steps* in my redux store. My my *steps* reducer manipulates the list of step by handling a series of actions:

- ADD_STEP_REQUEST
- REMOVE_STEP_REQUEST
- MOVE_STEP_UP_REQUEST
- MOVE_STEP_DOWN_REQUEST

So far so good.

I now have a requirement to perform a kind of validation every time there is a change to the order of the steps (or when a step is added or removed). During this validation I need to check each step to see if the step that precedes it fulfils certain criteria. I don't want to reject the changes if it doesn't. I just want to set an `isInvalid` flag on the step and ultimately change the way a step looks in the UI.

The simplest way I can handle this is adding a validateOrder() function (that applies the flags and returns the steps) that is run by the reducer at the end of each case statement:

```
case ADD_STEP_REQUEST: {
  const amendedSteps = // add a step
  return validateOrder(amendedSteps);
}

case REMOVE_STEP_REQUEST: {
  const amendedSteps = // remove a step
  return validateOrder(amendedSteps);
}

case MOVE_STEP_UP_REQUEST: {
  const amendedSteps = // reorder steps
  return validateOrder(amendedSteps);
}

case MOVE_STEP_DOWN_REQUEST: {
  const amendedSteps = // reorder steps
  return validateOrder(amendedSteps);
}
```

However, this feels wrong because I need to repeat the `validateOrder` call across all the case statements.

**Is there a better way to handle this?**

Answer (score 1):

A reducer is just a function. You can wrap it with another function:

```
const yourReducer = (state = 'your initial state', action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_STEP_REQUEST:
      // ...
      return amendedSteps

    case ...
  }
}

const validatedReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_STEP_REQUEST:
    case REMOVE_STEP_REQUEST:
    case MOVE_STEP_UP_REQUEST:
    case MOVE_STEP_DOWN_REQUEST:
      return validateOrder(yourReducer(state, action))

    default:
      return yourReducer(state, action)
  }
}
```

Now you separate the responsibilities. The original reducer doesn't need to care about the validation. The `validatedReducer` will take care of that.

If the `validateOrder` must be applied to all the cases, then you don't need the switch statement in `validatedReducer`, so it will become:

```
const validatedReducer = (state, action) =>
  validateOrder(yourReducer(state, action))
```